# How to submit wordpress form (file & name) with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am a new developer. I have created a plugin for data insert WP dashboard. I am trying to insert images in my database. I am trying to form submit with Ajax in WordPress. There is my code. When I use input type=text data submitted successfully, but when I use input type=file then data not submitted. I want all data inserted in my database and file saved in the upload folder.

```
 <form  id="ajax_form" method="" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?> " enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table class='wp-list-table widefat fixed'>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ss-th-width">Code</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="code" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" class="ss-field-width" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ss-th-width">School</th>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" class="ss-field-width" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ss-th-width">Image</th>
                    <td><?php wp_nonce_field('ajax_file_nonce', 'security'); ?>
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_file_upload">
                        <label for="file_upload">It's a file upload...</label>
                        <input type="file" name="file_upload">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type='submit' name="insert" value='Save' class='button'>

        </form>
```

Ajax code is here:

```
jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(ajaxformdata);   

    function ajaxformdata()
    {    
        var alldata = jQuery(this).serialize();    

        jQuery.ajax({  
            type:"POST",  
            //url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=signup", 
            url: "/mywp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=cruddata",                   
            data: alldata,  
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert('Data submited');
            },

            error: function(errorThrown)
            {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }  
        });    

        return false;  
    }
```

PHP code is here

```
<?php
function cruddata()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        $code = $_POST["code"];
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $imagesss = basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "school";

        $wpdb->insert(
             $table_name, //table
            array
                (
                    'code' => $code, 
                    'name' => $name
                    //'image_name' => $imagesss
                );
        $message.="Data inserted";
        }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_cruddata', 'cruddata' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this - On your JS your url should be `ajaxurl`, and action should be `cruddata` Hope this will works fine.

Register a method that perform your functionality

```
add_action('wp_ajax_cruddata', 'cruddata');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cruddata', 'cruddata');
```

Your function defination -

```
function cruddata() {
   // code goes here...
}
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    data: {
        'action': 'cruddata',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    url: ajaxurl,
    beforeSend: function () {
        //
    },
    success: function (data) {
        //
    }    
});
```

Comment: I think there's a small typo in your explanation: add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cruddata', 'cruddatat'); - should be 'cruddata', am I right?

Comment: Oh! Sorry!! Thanks for finding this mistake. Updated it :)

Comment: Where does ajaxurl come from?